# Change colour based on z height

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am using geometry nodes to move cylinders on the z location based on the proximity of an empty.

I wanted to use the attribute `dist` in a material to change the colour of the object as it should vary per object, that didn't work.

I tried to do this using the texture coordinate to get its z location and I found it just affects each object the same, makes it half and half but doesn't change on object's height.

How can I color each object based on its height, preferably using geometry nodes `dist` attribute that I created or as a last resort using the older method of texture coordinate node?

[image]

[image]

[download blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/be22d36d5b8d4d94b7a238f325680c26)

Comment: Hello, it's not exactly clear to me how the falloff should work, could you explain it a little bit more ? or add a diagram of expected behaviour ?

Comment: @Gorgious Sorry I have not explained it well. So when you move the empty, the nearer each instance is to the empty, the higher it will move on the z position. I want to colour objects that are higher in a different colour to when they are low on z position.

Comment: then i wonder why my answer was downvoted...

Answer (score 2):

you can change color based on z-position by this shader nodes:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: When I try this, I find that the colour does not change on the instances when I move the empty. They only change colour if I move the whole lot on the z position manually. I feel this is a limitation of geonodes right now.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to be careful of here.

One is, geo nodes do a strange mix of creating geometry and instancing, which do things differently, and not all the snags are worked out yet (and maybe we shouldn't expect all the snags to ever be worked out.)  This means that there are really two different sets of object coordinates, those for the instanced object and those for the instancing object, and making sure you use the right one is going to be tricky (and unintuitive, and maybe, break next release.)

And the same applies to the material.  Right now, you're not using a material on your instancing object, just on the instanced object.

So what we should do here, in order to adjust the color on the instancing object, is link the material onto that object (select instancer, shift select instanced, ctrl-l -> materials), and then use an attribute fill node at the end of the geo nodes to assign all the faces to the material-- assign all material_index to 0:

[image]

Now you can see that the material's object coordinates are, indeed, referring to the instancing object's coordinates, rather than the instanced object.

It's not clear that this is exactly what you want to happen.  But then, we'd need to know exactly what your goal was to address that.

Regarding "dist": it isn't really a property of the instanced geometry, just a property of the instancing mesh-- of the individual points on which the cylinders get instanced.  Those cylinders don't have any "dist" property.  In 2.93, instanced geometry doesn't really do VG-type attributes anyways.  (2.92, yes; 3.0, I sure hope so.)  However, if we trace your nodes, "dist" is a pretty simple vertex group that we could recreate with a vertex weight proximity modifier; or we could use a data transfer to copy it from a non-rendering, linked copy of the mesh, with different geo nodes (no instancing), and a "dist" VG group explicitly created on the object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what I want to happen is that each cylinder whole object changes colour as it changes height on z position, I think as you said its really the point position that changes, maybe I cannot do this.

Comment: @Neil Right now, in 2.93, you cannot simultaneously use properties of the instance (like the object coords you are using, but also many other things) and properties of the instancer.  That means that something has to give.  The simplest thing to give is dynamic instancing, which is to say, give up on geometry nodes.  But the ideal thing to give up depends on what your goals for this structure are, for example, how you want to animate it.

Comment: This is a big limitation of geometry nodes, not being able to use properties of the instances because there's not much point using instances in this way if you cannot do simple things like apply materials based on a z location.